# Why this brute force attack doesn't reduce all cryptographic hash functions' security bits against collision attacks to N/3?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, brute-force-attack

The traditional brute force collision attack is generate $2^{N/2}$ (unique) random strings, hash them and this results in ~50% chance for collision.
The attack talked in the question's title is generate hashes by the sequence $H_0 = F(S), H_n = F(S||H_{n-1})$, where $S$ is a string to make collision with, $F$ is the hash function, and the sequence stops at $2^{N/3}$.

The above attack needs less calls to the hash function because it relies on the fact that each sequential hashing reduces the number of possible hashes. When hashing $2^N$ random strings, there will be $(1-(1-\frac{1}{2^N})^{2^N})2^N$ possible hashes because of all the collisions.

The sequence that tells the fraction of the possible hashes for each hash in the sequence is $P_0 = 1, P_n = 1 - (1-\frac{1}{2^N})^{2^NP_{n-1}}$, which roughly approximates to $P_n = P_{n-1} - \frac{P_{n-1}^2}{2}$ as $\lim_{P_{n-1}\to 0}$, which can be approximated into a function $P(n) = \frac{2}{n + 2}$. (these reductions in precision make it easier for future calculations)

The chance for a collision to NOT happen for a hash in the sequence against all of it's following hashes is $C_n = (1 - \frac{1}{P_n2^N})^{M - n - 1}$ where $M$ is the sequence's length, because the fraction is so close to $1$, it can be approximated to $C_n = 1 - \frac{M - n}{P_n2^N} = 1 - \frac{Mn - n^2}{2^{N + 1}}$. Now to approximate the multiplication of all $C$s ($C_0C_1...C_M)$ to get the chance for collision for all hashes combined, we can discard the multiplication (because again, $C_n$ is very close to $1$) and add all the subtracted parts and subtract them from $1$, which results in $1 - \frac{M^3/2-M^3/4}{2^{N+1}} = 1 - \frac{M^3/4}{2^{N+1}}$, and to reach ~50% collision rate $M = 2^{(N+3)/3-1}$, which is just $2^{N/3}$.

Is there a reason why this won't work?

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. Could you elaborate `The above attack needs less calls to the hash function because it relies on the fact that each sequential hashing reduces the number of possible hashes.`

Comment: @kelalaka The sentence after that meant to support that statement, is it out of place?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $M$ be the number of queries to a uniform random function $F$ at distinct points $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_M$.  The probability of a repeated value $F(X_i) = F(X_j)$ for $i \ne j$ is *at most* $M^2\!\big/2^N$ by the birthday paradox.  For $M = 2^{N/3}$, this is $2^{2N/3}\!\big/2^N = 1\big/2^{N - 2N/3} = 1\big/2^{N/3}$.  If your calculation doesn't fit this bound, there's an error in your calculation.

‘But what if we come upon a short cycle in $H \mapsto F(S \mathbin\| H)$?’, you ask.  The expected number of points before a repeat in a uniform random function on a domain of $2^N$ elements is $\frac12\sqrt{2\pi\,2^N} - 1 \approx 2^{N/2}$ ([Harris 1960](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2237803) Eqs. 3.4 & 3.11, see paper for more details of distribution; [paywall-free](https://sci-hub.tw/https://www.jstor.org/stable/2237803)).  So no, this method doesn't improve the expected cost.

Using a clever tortoise-chasing-hare algorithm to find a cycle, rather than making a big table and checking for duplicates, may reduce the memory or area*time cost of an attack, as in the [van Oorschot–Wiener parallel collision search machine](http://people.scs.carleton.ca/~paulv/papers/JoC97.pdf), but it doesn't escape the birthday bound!

Comment: +1 for the classical reference to Harris, and a softcopy, which already has most of the results in later papers by crypto experts...

Comment: I feel like Harris's paper answers about a quarter of all the questions on this site!

Comment: I have chosen this answer because of the expected cycle length, this explains directly why it doesn't work.

Comment: Is the expected before repeat related to the birthday paradox by any chance?

Answer (score 4):

It is correct that the set of possible $H_n$ over all the possible $S$ reduces as $n$ grows. However the attack evaluates the $H_i$ for a fixed random $S$, not for multiple $S$; thus that reduction is immaterial to the success of the attack.

In other words: it is evaluated the number of possible $H_i$ for *random* $S$ as a function of $i$, and from that drawn conclusions for collision probability  among the $H_i$ for sequential $i$ and a *particular* $S$. The conclusions are thus not justified, and, it happens, quite incorrect.

When we model $F$ as a random function, then until there is a collision the $H_i$ are random, and hence the probability of collision among the $H_i$ with  $0\le i<n$ is per the birthday bound.

Comment: each $H_i$ is random from set of $2/(n+2)*2^N$ hashes, no? That's the whole point, it's the birthday problem, but reduced for each subsequent $H_i$.

Comment: @Yanai Eliyahu: more precisely, for any fixed $i$, $H_i$ is random in a set of size typicaly less than $2^N$ and reducing with $i$, when the seed $S$ is uniformly random. $n$ does not come into play here. An approximation of the size of this set may be $2/(i+2)*2^N$ (depending on the particular $H$), but again since the actual $S$ is fixed, the size of that set is immaterial to the probability of collision among the $H_i$ with $0\le i<n$

Comment: you mean because there is only 1 string, there is no collision?

Comment: @Yanai Eliyahu: yes, I mean that since there is a single $S$, there is single $H_i$ for any given $i$, Thus no collision for a given $i$. If we had a magic box that performs $i$ iterated hashes in a blink, and we used that box for many $S$, then the size of the set of the possible $H_i$ would matter. But no magic box in sight.

Comment: I edited the questions so it would make sense... I changed it to $H_n = F(S||H_{n-1})$, like that you can make $S$, and then the attack finds 2 different $2^N$-bits string that are concatenated to the original string to make a collision. Now it's OK?

Comment: @Yanai Eliyahu: my answer and comments apply to the modified question [though I wish I wrote "(depending on the particular $F$)" in my first comment].

Comment: Got it... it makes sense now, I tested that attack on fixed $S$, and it worked like normal birthday problem, but when I only used $H_0$ and $H_1$ and made many strings it worked as expected (improved collision chance), but reaching higher $M$ reduces the collision chance to the birthday problem.